# How could I replicate this Google Chart without using third party tool?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm not sure how to make auto adjusting column chart bars that will scale up and down depending on other column's values. Like, for example, if I had 5 columns where 4 of the 5 columns had a value of 0, and the last column had a value of 1, that bar would be "max value" and be really tall. But, if I made another bar go from 0 value to 2 value, then the 1 value bar would be half the size of the 2 value bar. Google Charts did all of that for me, which I like, but that's the only thing I like about Google Charts.

How can I make a chart much like the one below without using any third-party APIs?

https://jsfiddle.net/14eoL93k/

```
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load("current", {
    packages: ['corechart']
  });
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ["Mana Cost", "Cards"],
      ["0", 1],
      ["1", 0],
      ["2", 9],
      ["3", 1],
      ["4", 8],
      ["5", 3],
      ["6", 3],
      ["7+", 1],
    ]);

    var maxV = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
      if (data.getValue(i, 1) > maxV) {
        maxV = data.getValue(i, 1);
      }
    }
    maxV += maxV / 5;

    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setColumns([0, 1, {
      calc: "stringify",
      sourceColumn: 1,
      type: "string",
      role: "annotation",
    }, ]);

    var options = {
      title: "Cards/Mana Cost",
      width: '750',
      height: '375',
      backgroundColor: "#000",
      enableInteractivity: false,
      bar: {
        groupWidth: "95%",
      },
      legend: {
        position: "none"
      },
      annotations: {
        highContrast: false,
        alwaysOutside: true,
        stem: {
          color: "transparent"
        },
        textStyle: {
          fontName: 'Lato',
          fontSize: 18.75,
          auraColor: 'transparent',
          color: "#FFF"
        }
      },
      chartArea: {
        width: '95%',
        backgroundColor: "#000"
      },
      vAxis: {
        baselineColor: '#FFF',
        viewWindow: {
          max: maxV,
        },
        gridlines: {
          color: 'transparent'
        },
        textPosition: "none"
      },
      titleTextStyle: {
        color: "#FFF",
        fontName: "Lato",
        fontSize: 25
      },
      hAxis: {
        textStyle: {
          color: "#FFF",
          fontName: "Lato",
          fontSize: 18.75,
        }
      }
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("columnchart_values"));
    chart.draw(view, options);
  }

</script>
<div id="columnchart_values" style="width: 900px; height: 300px;"></div>
```

Comment: Although I too don't totally condone reinventing the wheel it could be a fun exercise creating a very simple API for the specific need in question. Could you show what you've done so far?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you should firstly try to figure out what's the matter with your website. APIs exist to avoid reinventing the wheel every time, and - from what I have read in your question - as soon as you're going to add a new feature, probably there will be similar issues. Anyway, to perform actions with drawables and graphs, you do need JavaScript, and not only HTML + CSS, as far as I know